# Monkey patch form in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-forms, monkeypatching

I have an app included into `INSTALLED_APPS` that needs to be monkey-patched.
The problem is that I don't explicitly import modules from this app (`django-allauth`).

Is there any way to get some access at the point when Django imports an application
and monkey patch one of it's internal forms?

Which in my case would be `socialaccount.forms.DisconnectForm.clean = smth`

Comment: What's happening now when you try to import it and patch it in one of your files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to copy the package to my application folder and patch it locally.

Answer (score -1):

import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() in the __init__ of the module. And write the char "w" to see the trace